# Page design breaks in mobile view for the first time

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am totally confused with a strange situation, I dont know whether it is a usual case, so pardon me if it is totally normal.
I have a page which works fine in almost all desktop resolutions. But when I check the page in my mobile view, for the first time, the design breaks. Then if I refresh the page everything becomes normal. Then after that onwards since the page is in browser cache , problem solved. What might be the cause of this issue. Thanks in advance.

I am loading the below specific script for my page in footer afetr loading jquery-1.11.1.min.js and before loading bootstrap.min.js

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".clsIPArtGalUL li:nth-child(1)").addClass("width-2x");
            $(".clsIPArtGalUL li:nth-child(4)").addClass("width-2x");

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe on load scripts crashing or collapse.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: how can I identify whether a script crash or collapse occurs or not?

Comment: check for proper meta tag addition. For responsive design

Answer (score 0):

This is probably from the fact that your jQuery code doesn't respond on [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)

If you add a function called `resize()` for all your code that you want to run when the page gets resized, use this code to call it when:

```
window.onresize = resize(); // The window is resized
resize(); // When this code is executed.
```

**Update**: One question, could you use:

```
.clsIPArtGalUL li:nth-child(1),
.clsIPArtGalUL li:nth-child(4) {
  /* .width-2x code here */
}
```

CSS tends to cause less bugs in mobile vs desktop.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but, the issue is not with resizing, it happens when i open my page from my mobile for the first time only.

Comment: When you say mobile, do you mean in a mobile device or when the screen is small?

Comment: In a mobile device.

Comment: Come to this chat room to discuss different things that could cause it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132450/chris-room